# How to use Snapchat in swift, Does an API exist?

Tags: swift, snapchat

I'm looking an iOS / Swift API to publish photo directly in user story. I can't find any information. Is it possible ? Somebody already do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Snapchat does not allow third party apps**, and does not allow third parties to connect to its private API, and does not provide developers with a public API.

**MORE INFO:-** https://www.snap.com/en-US/news/post/third-party-applications-and-the-snapchat-api/